# stream is not readable for 'raw-body' package in nest.js

Tags: nestjs

I try to get a raw webhook body using 'raw-body' package.
I get an error `stream is not readable`.

I know that in Nest.js there's an explicit solution for this, but I want to try this package intentionally.

Here is my code:

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Controller, Post, Req} from '@nestjs/common';
const getRawBody = require('raw-body')


@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
  @Post()
  async customerDataRequestSend(@Req() req) {
    const rawBody = await getRawBody(req)
    console.log(rawBody)
  }
  
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you end up figuring out the issue?

Comment: @TimWheeler yes I did, see the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should apply to any Express.js powered framework (such as Nest.js and [`routing-controllers`](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers)) involved with [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)'s `stream is not readable` error.

Let's use a simple Express.js app as an example.

```
import express from "express"
import getRawBody from "raw-body"

const app = express()

app.use(async (req, _res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body) // `undefined`

  const rawBody = await getRawBody(req, { encoding: "utf-8" })
  console.log(rawBody)

  next()
})

// Use `body-parser` middleware after
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post("*", (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

The main cause is `await` blocking `next()`. If we change the code to:

```
import express from "express"
import getRawBody from "raw-body"

const app = express()

app.use((req, _res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body) // `undefined`

  getRawBody(req, { encoding: "utf-8" }).then((rawBody) => {
    console.log(rawBody) // works!
  })

  next()
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post("*", (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body) // works too!
})

app.listen(8080)
```

No more `stream is not readable` errors.

---

Explanation:

We can simplify `getRawBody` (or even `body-parser`) to:

```
function getRawBody(req: Request): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let data = ""
    req.on("data", (chunk: Buffer) => {
      data += chunk.toString()
    })
    req.on("end", () => {
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

As you can see, the promise resolves only when the `req` `end`s. Before then `body-parser` should still be able to read the stream. This is why we shouldn't block `next()`'s invocation, which enables `body-parser` to consume the `req` stream simultaneously.